# lspci alternative to OEL/RHEL?

Tags: command-line, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am looking to list all PCI slots on a machine running Oracle Enterprise Linux 7. However the command lspci is not available. Are you aware of any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OEL 7 is based on RHEL 7. You should be able to find a package named ***pciutils*** that contains the `/usr/sbin/lspci` command. Not sure exactly how to do that on OEL but on RHEL its just

```
yum install pciutils
```